# findByUserIdAndPassword(userId, password);

Tags: java, dto

when iam trying to fetch the records with this query findByUserIdAndPassword(userId, password); using MongoRepository
but iam getting null all the time any suggestions?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginValidation(@RequestParam String userId,@RequestParam String password) {
        System.out.println("un"+userId);
        System.out.println("password"+password);
        Optional<TicketUserDto> ticketuser=ticketUserDao.findByUserIdAndPassword(userId, password);
}
```

Image of code:

[image: Image of code]

Comment: Show code of `ticketUserDao .findByUserIdAndPassword`

Comment: @Repository
public interface TicketUsersDao extends MongoRepository<TicketUserDto, Serializable> {
 
 Optional<TicketUserDto> findByUserIdAndPassword(String userId,String password);
}

Comment: Do userId and password print there which you inputed while calling the api?

Comment: both userId and password are printing only problem with the query

Comment: when i call findAll() method iam getting the values.